# Need help to tune a complex query

Tags: mysql, performance

I am trying to performance tune a query and need help with that

We have a requirement to pull in data on the website based on multiple factors which resulted in a complex query which works fine but is expensive. We have all the correct indexes.

What I am stuck on is removing the use of DISTINCT in the query (which seems to be the bottleneck).

I am no SQL expert and I think I've tried everything I could.

Any help to simplify this query and remove DISTINCT (or not use GROUP BY) will be much appreciated.  Thanks.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  t2.PK  
FROM categories t0 
    JOIN cat2catrel t1 ON  t1.SourcePK  =  t0.PK  
    JOIN categories t2 ON  t1.TargetPK  =  t2.PK  
    JOIN cat2catrel t3 ON  t3.SourcePK  =  t2.PK  
    JOIN categories t4 ON  t3.TargetPK  =  t4.PK  
    JOIN cat2prodrel t5 ON  t5.SourcePK = t4.PK  
    JOIN products t6 ON  t5.TargetPK  =  t6.PK  
    JOIN stocklevels t7 ON  t7.productcode  =  t6.code  
    JOIN relativeinventory t8 ON  t7.p_inventory  =  t8.PK  
    JOIN warehouses t9 ON  t7.warehouse  =  t9.PK  
    JOIN pos2warehouserel t10 ON  t10.TargetPK  =  t9.PK  
    JOIN pos2warehouserel t10 ON  t10.TargetPK  =  t9.PK  
    JOIN pointofservice item_t11 ON  t10.SourcePK  =  t11.PK  
    WHERE  ( t0.code  = 'code' 
        AND  t8.nventorystatus  IN (1111) 
        AND  t11.name  = 'ABC') 
        AND ((t0.TypePkString IN  (1, 2, 3, 4)  
        AND (( t0.catalogversion  IN (1, 2, 3)))  
        AND t1.TypePkString=1000 
        AND t2.TypePkString IN  (1, 2, 3, 4)  
        AND (( t2.catalogversion  IN (1, 2)))  
        AND t3.TypePkString=300  
        AND t4.TypePkString IN  (6, 7, 8)  
        AND (( t4.catalogversion  IN (5, 6)))  
        AND t5.TypePkString=500 
        AND t6.TypePkString=600 
        AND t7.TypePkString=200  
        AND t8.TypePkString=700 
        AND t9.TypePkString IN  (3, 7)  
        AND t10.TypePkString=900  
        AND t11.TypePkString=750 ));
```

Currently, this query works fine and provides the results I want.  I just don't want to use DISTINCT or GROUP BY and still get unique results.

DB:  MySQL 6.3

Comment: You can try a bunch of EXISTS subqueries.

Comment: Why not use DISTINCT or GROUP BY? What you are trying to do is what they are made for, What does the EXPLAIN show for your current query?

Comment: MySQL is _usually_ pretty good about using conditions in the WHERE clause to reduce the number of rows it has to handle, but in a larger query like this, that functionality can kind of fall apart. In this particular case, you might want to consider changing the table references into subqueries that handle their corresponding WHERE conditions ahead of the JOIN. _Alternatively, you can use those subqueries for a series of `IN (subquery)` conditions in the WHERE clause._

Comment: Note: If using the solution my comment above suggested, the JOIN version will still need DISTINCT, but it might be faster so that DISTINCT is not an issue; the IN version should not need DISTINCT though. _But due to the inter-relation between tables, it does not look like a pure IN version is possible._

Comment: There is no `MySQL 6.3`.  Use `SELECT @@version;`.

Comment: It smells like a case of "over-normalization".

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Many:many tables should have composite indexes; see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Answer (score 0):

Your only selecting t2.pk, which appears to be the primary key in the categories table. If this is correct, your producing duplication with your Joins. The easiest solution in general to get rid of DISTINCT in this scenario is to start with the table that you are selecting from and ensuring your INNER JOINING to it. However, it appears your actually doing this already, but your duplicating the join... i.e. t0 and t2 are the same table which is a big red flag to me. Try something like this:

```
SELECT t0.PK  
FROM categories t0 
    INNER JOIN cat2catrel t1 ON  t1.SourcePK  =  t0.PK AND t1.TargetPK = t0.PK
    INNER JOIN cat2catrel t3 ON  t3.SourcePK  =  t0.PK  
    INNER JOIN categories t4 ON  t3.TargetPK  =  t4.PK  
    INNER JOIN cat2prodrel t5 ON  t5.SourcePK = t4.PK  
    INNER JOIN products t6 ON  t5.TargetPK  =  t6.PK  
    INNER JOIN stocklevels t7 ON  t7.productcode  =  t6.code  
    INNER JOIN relativeinventory t8 ON  t7.p_inventory  =  t8.PK  
    INNER JOIN warehouses t9 ON  t7.warehouse  =  t9.PK  
    INNER JOIN pos2warehouserel t10 ON  t10.TargetPK  =  t9.PK  
    INNER JOIN pos2warehouserel t10 ON  t10.TargetPK  =  t9.PK  
    INNER JOIN pointofservice item_t11 ON  t10.SourcePK  =  t11.PK  
    WHERE  ( t0.code  = 'code' 
        AND  t8.nventorystatus  IN (1111) 
        AND  t11.name  = 'ABC') 
        AND ((t0.TypePkString IN  (1, 2, 3, 4)  
        AND (( t0.catalogversion  IN (1, 2, 3)))  
        AND t1.TypePkString=1000 
        AND t2.TypePkString IN  (1, 2, 3, 4)  
        AND (( t2.catalogversion  IN (1, 2)))  
        AND t3.TypePkString=300  
        AND t4.TypePkString IN  (6, 7, 8)  
        AND (( t4.catalogversion  IN (5, 6)))  
        AND t5.TypePkString=500 
        AND t6.TypePkString=600 
        AND t7.TypePkString=200  
        AND t8.TypePkString=700 
        AND t9.TypePkString IN  (3, 7)  
        AND t10.TypePkString=900  
        AND t11.TypePkString=750 ));
```

However I see other tables duplicated to like "pos2warehouserel". **Tables should only be declared and assigned an alias once.**

Comment: Actually, it is very common to reference tables multiple times within queries; and each reference requires a different alias. In this particular case, the query is probably handling a "subcategory".  .but yes, a table alias can only be used once within a particular query. I'd guess the double t10 in the question is just a error from copying the query into the question, as it would not execute at all if it were in the query being used.

Comment: Perhaps it is common, so are software security vulnerabilities... I'm of a belief that an "optimized query" is one where you do not do this, because it is unnecessary, confusing, inefficient, uninterpretable and unpredictable; declarations should be in relational order IMHO, i.e. same order as the arrows point. I would have to see the DB schema, but I suspect this query could be 1/2 as many lines as it currently is and much faster. I mean, we have pos2warehouserel declared as t10 w/ the same ON TWICE! Precisely why you should get in the habit of only declaring an alias once.

Comment: Which is the "this" you are referring to? Using an alias more than once? MySQL, and as far as I know all other major RDBMS, do not even allow that. _(Aside from subqueries, which I would agree re-using aliases in those cases is poor form and makes queries unnecessarily hard to read.)_ If you're referring to using tables multiple times in the same query, there are no inherent problems with doing so, and many problems that cannot be solved without doing so.

Comment: IMHO, a table name should only appear once in a query if it has an alias which means every table should have at most one alias. With or without an alias, IMHO I believe a table should only be joined to once for 99% of all queries. i.e. Instead of doing two joins from table A ON A.pk and B ON B.pk to table C ON C.pk, for example, you can join table C ON C.pk=A.pk AND C.pk=B.pk. i.e. multiple joins to the same table aren't necessary thanks to the AND clause in the ON statement... and, I suspect/recall strongly, this results in faster and neater queries. Joins are expensive.

Comment: When table `a` has a `from_b_id` and a `to_b_id` field, good luck getting information about a source and destination together in one result row without joining twice. The `b.id` of a row can't be two values at the same time. JOINs are one the most basic things you can do in an RDMBS, they are pretty much the main way of leveraging the R in RDBMS; they're only expensive if your data is not indexed and/or poorly structured.

Comment: And yet, if a and b were related in this way I would say that the database needs to be redesigned; This assumes relationality is enforced and all relationships are identifying relationships... which they should always be IMHO.